# va_args in c from <stdarg.h> does not work correctly

Tags: c, printf, variadic-functions

I am trying to write my own printf function in c, but I faced with a problem,
when I want to call my functions with this arguments :

> ft_printf ("Characters: %c %c\n",'s','e');

instead of getting  **'s'** **'e'** , I got **'s'** **'s'**.
It looks like it does not go through all arguments,

this is my function :

```
    static int get_args(va_list args, char format)
    {
  if(format == 'c')
      return(print_char(va_arg(args,int))); //here I called va_args to retrieve args
    }
   

 int    ft_printf(const char *format, ...)
    {
        va_list args;
        int i;
        int len;
        
        len = 0;
        i = 0;
        
        va_start(args,format);
        while (format[i])
        {
            if (format[i] == '%')
            {
                      len += get_args(args, format[i + 1]);
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                      write(1,&format[i],1);
                      len++;
                }
            i++;
        }
        va_end(args);
        return len;
    
    }

int main()
{
    printf ("Characters: %c %c \n",'s','e');
    ft_printf ("Characters: %c %c\n",'s','e');
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `va_arg ` is a **macro** that does nasty things. It somewhat *modifies* its `va_list` argument, so you cannot use it outside `ft_printf`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After passing `args` to `get_args()` and calling `va_arg` inside, the value of the original `args` in `ft_printf()` is indeterminate†, and you can only `va_end` it.

However, if you pass it by reference (with a pointer), it properly updates `args` in the original function:

```c
static int get_args(va_list *args, char format)
{
  if (format == 'c')
      // here I called va_args to retrieve args
      return print_char(va_arg(*args, int));
}


int ft_printf(const char *format, ...)
{
    // ...
    len += get_args(&args, format[i + 1]);
    // ...
}
```

---

† On some platforms, `va_list` is a type like an integer or pointer, so `get_args` receives a copy and `va_arg` can't update the original. On other platforms, it's an array type, so the function parameter becomes a pointer so it's automatically passed "by reference" and the original value *is* updated. You appear to be using a platform with the former type, where `args` in `ft_printf` isn't modified.

Comment: you were right, but I did not completely got what was the problem exactly, could you explain a little bit more? thanks a lot